# Impute NA values with previous value in R

Tags: r

We have 101 variables (companys) their closing prices. We got a lot of NA values (because the stock market closes on saturdays and sundays -> gives NA value in our data) and we need to impute those NA values with the previous value if there is a previous value but we don't succeed. [This is our data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjlCq.png)

There are also companies that don't have data in the first years since they were not on the stock market so they have NA values for this period. And there are companies that go bankrupt and start having NA values so these should both become 0. 
How should we do this since we have several conditions for filling our NA's

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `na.locf` function

Comment: 1. don't use an image, do `head(my data)` and paste it into your question above. 2. Several columns have `NA` which is/are the ones you need to fix?

Comment: @abhiieor OK what package is `na.locf` in then?

Comment: this is frustrating  - a decent but half set question and a half answer in comments.

Comment: Just for completeness, `na.locf` is from the `zoo`-package

Comment: Timestamp XOMA.OQ TGTX.OQ SYN.A EBN.V    BTX.A PDLI.OQ    VER.L   LGND.OQ BION.S OPT.AX  PGNX.OQ MORG.DE  SRPT.OQ PRM.L
      <dttm>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2007-01-02   NA    NA    NA  NA     NA      NA       NA 1003.7582     NA     NA 1.519857      NA 18.23332    NA
2 2007-01-03      NA     648    NA    NA 8.276965      NA 14.27911  999.7592  65.46  18.80 1.612710   26.66 18.54998 18.54
3 2007-01-04   NA   663    NA    NA 8.569871   NA 14.67733 1031.7515  66.96  18.62 1.602936  27.06 18.36665 19.20

Comment: this is head(data2)

Comment: @StephenHenderson sorry for your frustrations, but this is the first time I use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the rules are:

- columns that are all NA are to be left as all NA
- leading NA values are left as NA
- interior NA values are replaced with the most recent non-NA values
- trailing NA values are replaced with 0

To try this out we use the built-in data frame `BOD` replacing the 1st, 3rd and last rows with `NA` and adding a column of `NA` values -- see Note at end.

We define a logical vector `ok` having one element per column which is `TRUE` for columns having at least one element that is not `NA` and `FALSE` for other columns.  Then operating only on the columns for which `ok` is `TRUE` we fill in the trailing `NA` values with `0` using `na.fill`.  Then we use `na.locf` to fill in the interior `NA` values.

```
library(zoo)

ok <- !apply(is.na(BOD), 2, all)
BOD[, ok] <- na.locf(na.fill(BOD[, ok], c(NA, NA, 0)), na.rm = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
  Time demand  X
1   NA     NA NA  <-- leading NA values are left intact
2    2   10.3 NA
3    2   10.3 NA  <-- interior NA values are filled in with last non-NA value
4    4   16.0 NA
5    5   15.6 NA
6    0    0.0 NA  <- trailing NA values are filled in with 0
```

### Note

We used the following input above:

```
BOD[c(1, 3, 6), ] <- NA
BOD <- cbind(BOD, X = NA)
```

### Update

Fix.

Comment: The leadings should be 0 as well and if I use your code will that apply to all my colums because I got 101 colums.

Comment: Use `c(0, NA, 0)` in `na.fill` if you want both leading and trailing NA values to be 0.   We can see from the reprodudible example in the answer that it handled all columns.

Comment: ok <- !apply(is.na(data2), 2, all)
data2[, ok] <- na.locf(na.fill(data2[, ok], c(0, NA, 0)), na.rm = FALSE) so data2 is my dataframe. I get an error as following: Error in if (is.character(fill[[2]]) && fill[[2]] == "extend") object[wrng] <- approx(wix,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I thought it had something to do with my first column that is of date and has no NA values so I tried subsetting ok <- !apply(is.na(data2[2:101]), 2, all) but I still get the same error

Comment: I will need a small reproducible example that illustrates the problem such as the one that I provided in the answer.  (Note that SO questions are expected to have minimal complete reproducible examples in them and that is why you got so many downvotes.  See [mcve].)